# Delete all untracked files from TeamCity working copy as part of checkout from SVN

Tags: teamcity

In our setup, TeamCity builds a Visual Studio solution, checked out by a SVN VCS root. The build process leaves some generated content in the working copy that TeamCity checked out (.dll's transformed .config files and such), and this is causing trouble.

My solution to the problem is to enable "*Clean all files before build*" under checkout settings. This is not optimal, as i slows down the build process significantly.

I've come across an option in the VCS root to "*Revert before update*", but [the documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Subversion) clearly states, that this will only revert tracked files.

Is there a way that I can have TeamCity delete all untracked files from the working copy, as part of the checkout process, before building the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Build Files Cleaner (Swabra)](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Files+Cleaner+%28Swabra%29) Build Step of TeamCity.

Comment: @magnuskragelund, be careful. It does not work correct with symlinks.

Comment: When Swabra find changed files in output directory, it clean whole directory instead of changed files only.